# generate java google endpoints server stub from swagger API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, swagger, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm looking for a way to generate a server stub for a java google endpoints backend project from a swagger API (yaml/json file).

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Asaf

Answer (score 2):

You should explore swagger code-gen.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#to-generate-a-sample-client-library

You can also explore Restlet studio : https://studio.restlet.com/apis/local/info (Server-skeletons and choose).

hope it helps

Comment: thanks!
I've looked at the swagger documentation, 
you referred to the client generator chapter, there is another chapter there that i saw which could be relevant:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846198/generate-java-google-endpoints-server-stub-from-swagger-api
but I was hoping that there is a easier way for this.
and I'll check the second link!

Comment: Sure , let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to import your Swagger/OpenAPI spec into https://editor.swagger.io and in the top menu bar click on "Generate Server" and then select Java-related server stub (e.g. JAX-RS, Spring and more)

Or you can install Swagger Codegen locally. Here is a good starting point:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#getting-started